# Is there a way to run AudioKit on watchOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui, audiokit, watchos, watchos-7

I am trying to use AudioKit for a WatchOS app I'm working on. I tried both building from git and using pods but neither has worked. I know on their website it shows support for only iOS, iPadOS, macOS, and tvOS but I wanted to know if there is a workaround for watchOS? I only need to use the Core components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last I checked on this, the necessary APIs in AVFoundation were simply not available, so we didn't bother to make a port to this platform.

Looking at the latest API documentation however, it looks like they may have filled in some of these gaps in later watchOS releases so it might be possible now - might be worth revisiting though there hasn't been a whole lot of demand for it.